# Git - why is my source file ignored?

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm using git version 2.15.0.windows.1

I have the following in my gitignore file:

```
#BAM
**/*[Bb][Aa][Mm]/*
!**/*[Bb][Aa][Mm]/*.btt
!**/*[Bb][Aa][Mm]/*.xls
!**/*[Bb][Aa][Mm]/*.xlsx
```

My understanding is that the third line tells git to track files matching the pattern ending *.btt. This is a *Don't* ignore because of the preceding *!*

My problem is, my file *eformsV2.btt* is being ignored. 
I used the the *git check-ignore* command and it came back with the pattern as shown below:

[image]

The documentation ([git doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore)) suggests that check-ignore only displays a path for a file it believes is being ignored - which is correct, but why is the *!* prefix of the pattern not causing the file to be tracked?

Comment: Is that really a minimal example? Is the `**/*[Bb][Aa][Mm]` part necessary or can that be simplified and still reproduce the problem?

Comment: So I tried changing the rule to !*.btt but still eformsV2.btt is ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question I have is whether the file is actually being ignored.  (Git's `check-ignore` will tell you which rule matches a file, even if that's a "don't ignore" rule.)

I made a test directory and copied your sample `.gitignore` file into it, then
made two subdirectories:

```
$ mkdir eforms eforms/eformsV2.Bam
$ cd eforms/eformsV2.Bam/
$ touch ignoreme
$ touch eformsV2.btt
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        ../
$ git status -uall
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        eformsV2.btt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
git check-ignore -v eformsV2.btt 
.gitignore:3:!**/*[Bb][Aa][Mm]/*.btt    eformsV2.btt
```

Except for the fact that I ran `git status` twice and showed (with the second, more verbose, `-uall` variant) that `eformsV2.btt` is *not* being ignored, this seems to match your screenshot.

---

Running `git status -uall` is useful when `git status` without `-uall` shows only a directory, since all you know at that point is: *some files in the directory are not in the index, but neither are they ignored*.  The view from higher up makes a bit more sense:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        eforms/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Since there are no files *within* `eforms/` itself that are tracked—which is true even though those files are within a *subdirectory* of `eforms`—Git has abbreviated the list-of-all-such-files as simply `eforms/`, not `eforms/eformsV2.Bam/`.  But `git check-ignore -v` points you to the line that tells you why the file *isn't* ignored.

---

Note also that the presence or absence of a path name in `.gitignore` does not affect whether the file is *actually tracked*.  This is controlled strictly by whether the file is *in the index right now*.  If the path name is stored in the index, the file is tracked; if the path name is not in the index, the file is untracked.  The `.gitignore` entry mainly tells Git whether it should *complain* about the untracked file.  (It has a side effect of permitting Git to clobber the file as well, in some cases.)